# getSelection() by Double Click or manual selection is not the same

Tags: jquery, double-click, getselection

I allow me to ask a question, because I have a little probleme with an function which returns me the parent of a selection.

```
$('input[type=button].btn_transform').click(function(){        

    var selectionObj = getSelected();//Function which gives me selection

    var theParent=selectionObj.anchorNode.parentNode;
    alert (theParent);    
})
```

For example with this sentence : "the cat is `<strong>`gray`</strong>`."

If I select manually the word "gray" and click on my button, the function returns me ***[object HTMLSpanElement]***.

But if I select the same word by double clicking, the function returns me ***[object HTMLParagraphElement]***.

Do you know why ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The mouse selecting is creating a selection that encompasses all of but entirely lives inside the text node with text "gray". Double clicking is creating a selection that includes the whole of the `<strong>` element containing that text node. There may be no visual difference but the difference exists, as reflected in the `anchorNode`, `anchorOffset`, `focusNode` and `focusOffset` properties of the selection (or any Range you obtain from the selection). If pipes represent the selection boundaries, what you have is the following:

**Mouse selection:**

`the cat is <strong>|gray|</strong>`

**Double click selection:**

`the cat is |<strong>gray</strong>|`